# jaro-winkler with several lines

Tags: java, netbeans, jaro-winkler

I want to calculate the similarity between several lines, I found the distance jaro-winkler but only with two string, how can I replace these two string with several lines (from note pad)?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean you want to find the Jaro–Winkler distance distance between more than 2 strings? Or are you asking how to extract several lines from a notepad file?

Comment: i mean i want to fing the jaro-winkler distance between several lines for example: rania,abir,naimi
ran,kabir,naimia
ainar,bira,niami
rano,onran,imiam
.. etc